# How to generate a list from an iterator and some arbitrary function

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I'd like to generate a table of integers:

```
Table[i, {i, 10}]
```

Great; now suppose I want only the integers that are even

```
Select[Table[i, {i, 10}], EvenQ]
```

This is fine for small things, but if I'd like to iterate over say $2^{n}$ things, only maybe $n$ of which will satisfy the predicate, it's a pretty terrible way to do it.

Is there some good idiomatic way to do it? I could use a `Do` loop (I guess with `Append`ing?) but there must be a better way, right?

Comment: You could use `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` with `Do[]`; e.g. `Reap[Do[If[EvenQ[k], Sow[k]], {k, 10}]][[-1, 1]]`.

Comment: Yeah; that's basically what I had in mind. Interestingly, it doesn't appear to be particularly fast (though at least it probably doesn't waste memory like the `Select` option would do ...)

Comment: It's Scylla and Charybdis, I think: you could have it fast, but at the expense of memory, or memory-conserving, but rather slow...

Comment: Of course, sometimes problems have a pattern/structure that allow you to do these things more cleverly. In this simple case, you could do `Table[2 i, {i, 1, 5}]` or `Table[i, {i, 2, 10, 2}]` for instance; so, exploit patterns when you can!

Comment: Well, at the moment I can't make such a trade. The `Select` is slow (I believe) because it creates an inappropriately large array. `Do` with `Reap/Sow` also seems unfortunately slow. I was hoping there was a more idomatic (and so hopefully fast) way.

Comment: Haha, indeed J. M. in my actual case the things I want to find are less straightfoward.

Comment: Can you maybe include you *actual* problem? As I said, there might be structure in your problem that can allow a different solution...

Comment: The best way, of course, if you know the mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to your set. In the toy example you mentioned:
`2 Range[Quotient[len,2]]`, or even `Range[2,len,2]` does the same as 
`Select[Table[i,{i,len}],EvenQ]`

Comment: J. M: Not really, no. The point is it's basically arbitrary; imagine my predicate just randomly returns `True` when passed an integer.

Comment: If you can pregenerate the list of integers that will work, then you can use another form of table: `Table[...,{i, {list of ints that meet predicate}]`.

Comment: rcollyer: Indeed, but I can't do that. Or, put another way, that's equivalent to my original problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that `EvenQ` is merely an example; clearly if you can generate these values directly, e.g. `Range[2, 20, 2]` that will always be preferable.

You can do this reasonably efficiently in terms of both syntax and memory by using `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
test = Divisible[#, 1*^6] &;

Reap[Do[If[test @ i, Sow @ i], {i, 1*^6}]][[2, 1]]

(* Out= *)
{1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 7000000, 8000000, 9000000, 10000000}
```

Note that only a small amount of memory is used, unlike the `Table` and `Select` method:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 15467904
> ```

If you need greater performance you might make use of a block-based approach as I did for [Iterate until condition is met](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584/121), e.g.

```
block = 100000;

Join @@ Table[Select[Range[n block + 1, (n + 1) block], test], {n, 0, 99}]

(* Out= *)
{1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 7000000, 8000000, 9000000, 10000000}
```

This a bit faster than the first method on my system.

Comment: Thanks; I think your block approach is turning out to be perhaps what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly recommend *against* using `Append` for this task, as this is a very inefficient way to go.

One alternative would be to use `Fold` to build up a highly nested list and then `Flatten` at the very end, like this:

```
testdata = Range[10000];
Fold[If[Random[] < 0.2, {#1, #2}, #1] &, {}, testdata] // Flatten
```

Of course you would change the first argument of the `If` statement to whatever your real predicate is. Timing on my nearly four-year-old MacBook Pro is about 0.02 seconds for 10000 integers.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  Is this supposed to be faster than `Select`?  On my system at least it is slower.  It also does not save memory over `Select` that I can see.  What am I missing?

Comment: Fair enough - I was responding to the "alternatives to `Append`" element to the question. Your answer is clearly better, but mine is simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be a jerk; I really figured I was missing something (I often am).

Comment: You weren't being a jerk, don't worry.