# On reimplementing the Select function

Tags: programming

I am working through the course *Programming Paradigms via Mathematica*. One of the exercises asks that you construct a function that mimics `Select`,even with three arguments. It also includes the following direction:

> Do not use the `Select[]` function in your definition.

Here is an example of how `Select` works:

```
Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10}, EvenQ, 4]
(* {2, 4, 6, 8} *)
```

First I tested the following code and got the same result as `Select`:

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10};
l2 = {};
crit = EvenQ;
n = 4;
While[Length[l1] > 0 && Length[l2] < n,
 If[crit[First[l1]], l2 = Append[l2, First[l1]]];
    l1 = Rest[l1];
 ]
l2

(* {2, 4, 6, 8} *)
```

I then tried to write a function that would do the same thing (caution causes infinite loop):

```
Clear[whileSelect]
whileSelect[l1_List, crit_, n_] := Module[{l2},
  While[Length[l1] > 0 && Length[l2] < n,
    If[crit[First[l1]], l2 = Append[l2, First[l1]]];
        l1 = Rest[l1];
    ]
   l2
  ]
```

However I got a series of `Set::shape: Lists {1,2,3,4,6,8,10} and {2,3,4,6,8,10} are not the same shape. >>` error messages and the code put the computer into an infinite loop. I have looked at documentation on `Module`,`Rest`,`Set` and `If` but have not been able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: You're supposed to store `l1` in a temporary variable. Try `whileSelect[l1_List, crit_, n_] := Module[{l1temp = l1, l2}, (* stuff *)]`. `l1 = Rest[l1]` will not work because if, say, you executed `whileSelect[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10}, EvenQ, 3]`, you then encounter absurdities like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10} = Rest[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10}]` due to replacement. But I'll let someone else flesh out the details...

Comment: @0x4A4D, OK, I changed `Module[{l2}...` to `Module[{l1temp = l1, l2}...` I also changed all the instances of `l1` inside the definition to `l1temp`, however I just get error messages and `(*Null Hold[Append[l2$29158, 2], 2, 2, 2,...*)`

Comment: Consider `whileSelect[l1_List, crit_, n_Integer] := Module[{l1temp = l1, l2 = {}, temp}, While[Length[l1temp] > 0 && Length[l2] < n, temp = First[l1temp]; If[crit[temp], AppendTo[l2, temp]]; l1temp = Rest[l1temp]]; l2]`, and note well what I did differently.

Comment: @0x4A4D, Yes, that works +1. Now let me see if I can understand why. I am going to run it with `Trace` to see if I can understand how `l1temp=Rest[l1temp]` worked, whereas `l1=Rest[l1]` didn't, it may take a while.

Comment: Closed as already answered, as I specifically addressed this issue [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18737#18737).

Comment: outline of a "mathematica-idiomatic" way: `Take[Pick[list, fQ /@ list, True], max]`

Comment: @amr A problem with that construct is that the test (`fQ`) is applied to every `list` element; a second problem occurs if `max` exceeds the number of matches.  Also, there is no need for `True` in `Pick` as that is the default.  If one chooses not to use built-in functions with a length parameter (e.g. `Cases`) I would use something like: `select[lst_List, crit_, n_: Infinity] := Module[{f, r = 0},
  f = If[r < n, If[crit@#, r++; Sow @ #], Return[]] &;
  Reap[f ~Scan~ lst][[2, 1]]
  ]` with a [block-based optimization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21589/121) if appropriate.

Comment: @mr.Wizard aye, that form is what i would use in my own little codes, it's not meant for performant robustitude. your function is almost exactly what i was going to post before the thread was closed, except with pattern matching on the output of `Reap` like this: `{{_, {}} -> {}, {_, {out_}} :> out}` to handle the case where the length is 0. then again, that could just be checked in the beginning. derp derp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you want to do.

```
Clear[whileSelect]
whileSelect[l1_List, crit_, n_] := Module[{l1temp = l1, l2 = {}},
  While[Length[l1temp] > 0 && Length[l2] < n, 
   If[crit[First[l1temp]], l2 = Append[l2, First[l1temp]]];
   l1temp = Rest[l1temp];
   ];
   Return[l2];
  ]
```

The important lesson for you is, that you have to declare a local variable for l1 because an argument is not considered a variable by mathematica. So when you wrote `l1 = Rest[l1]`, mathematica tried to assign a list to a list, not change any variables.

BTW: The code still contains some flaws, but it shows the essential changes. I also recommend using Return, though just writing l2 without semicolon would suffice, too.

Comment: thank you, declaring a local variable is a good point. I'll try to keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: While this answer did not address the default value of `n` case, it did clearly state where I had made a mistake ,local value as opposed to argument.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is along the same lines as Wizard's, but I don't think `Return` is necessary or desirable. Also, to mimic `Select` better, the 3rd argument needs have the default value ∞.

```
whileSelect[l1_List, crit_, n : (_Integer | ∞) : ∞] /; n > 0 :=
  Module[{t = l1, l2 = {}},
    While[Length[t] > 0 && Length[l2] < n, 
      If[crit[First[t]], l2 = Append[l2, First[t]]];
      t = Rest[t]];
  l2]
```

Then you have

```
whileSelect[Range@10, EvenQ, 3]
```

> {2, 4, 6}

But, if you omit the 3rd argument, you get

```
whileSelect[Range@10, EvenQ]
```

> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

and the following doesn't evaluate

```
whileSelect[Range@10, EvenQ, -2]
```

> whileSelect[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, EvenQ, -2]

Note; `Select` prints an error message in this last case. I leave implementing that behavior as a exercise :-)

#### Edit

Here is a more functional-style implementation:

```
altSelect[l1_List, crit_, n : (_Integer?Positive | ∞)] :=
  Module[{u},
    Take[u = altSelect[l1, crit], Min[Length@u, n]]]
altSelect[l1_List, crit_] :=
  (crit@# && #) & /@ l1 /. False :> Sequence[]
```

Comment: ...or, one could have done `n : (_Integer?Positive | Infinity) : Infinity`.

Comment: @0x4A4D. Yes, that's better.

Comment: Thank You and yes, setting the default value for `n` was next on the todo list, and I can't say that I had a good idea. I will work on error message generation for the case of `-n`. I also appreciate the functional-style, I guess I would call it recursive, code. I can't say that I understand it, but I will look forward to studying it.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it's time to put in my take:

```
mySelect[list_List, crit_, n : (_Integer?Positive | ∞) : ∞] := Block[{k = 0}, 
         Reap[Scan[If[crit @ # && (++k) <= n, Sow[#]] &, list]][[-1, 1]]]
```

where I use `Scan[]` to loop though the input list and `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` to accumulate the elements selected according to the set criterion.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I went back and changed the original code again replacing `l1` with `l1temp` as you had suggested in the first comment and it worked, I must have made a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-line function that doesn't use `If` or `While`, but instead vectorizes the list into True/False, then uses these to index into the list.

```
sel[list_, crit_, maxLen_] := 
  Take[out = Rest@list[[Union[Range[Length[list]]  Boole[crit /@ list]]]], 
       Min[maxLen, Length[out]]]
```

For example:

```
sel[Range[10], OddQ, 4]

{1, 3, 5, 7}
```

Comment: Thank you for working on this. I am going to study the `Take[out=...` some more so that I'll understand what it is doing.

Comment: @Clif -- It is simpler than it might appear: it assigns the variable `out` to the right hand side of the equals sign. You are used to seeing this in a separate line of code; here it is used inside a function (in this case, `Take`) to do the definition. The `Take` command removes all but the first several entries, either `maxLen` or `Length[out]`, whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easiest, probably:

```
sel[list_, crit_, n_: Infinity] := Cases[list, _?crit, 1, n]
```

Almost seems like cheating.  This one is similar.

```
sel[list_, crit_, n_: Infinity] := Extract[list, Position[list, _?crit, 1, n]]
```

The problem is that there are so many ways to do the same thing.  I can't tell from the statement of the question whether a program from "scratch" was desired, or to search out more-or-less ready-made substitutes.  (I'm not familiar with the book.)

Comment: Thanks for helping, I am looking over the documentation on `Cases` and `Extract`.