# Finding primes that have certain property

Tags: number-theory, homework, prime-numbers

Let `S[p]` denote the sum of digits of `p`. A prime `p` is said to be stubborn if none of `S[n] + 1`, `S[n]`, `S[n] - 1`, `S[n] - 2` , or `S[n] - 3` is a prime. Write a Mathematica code that finds the smallest stubborn prime and tell which prime is it?

Comment: Hi there! Have you written the code for `S` yet?

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: yeah in fact it is a homework :$

Comment: @user116988 In that case, you should use the `homework` tag.

Comment: What's `n`? It should be `p`, right?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a direct approach:

```
digitsum = Composition[Total, IntegerDigits];

stubbornQ = PrimeQ[#] && Nor @@ PrimeQ[digitsum[#] - {1, 2, 3, 0, -1}] &;

i = 1;
While[! stubbornQ[++i]]
i
```

> 8999

This was quite sufficient in this case.  For larger search spaces see [Iterate until condition is met](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584/121).

---

A bit more efficient for v10+ using [`NoneTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NoneTrue.html) for early exit:

```
stubbornQ = PrimeQ[#] && NoneTrue[digitsum[#] - {1, 2, 3, 0, -1}, PrimeQ] &
```

Comment: 999 is not a prime

Comment: @becko lol -- well, I couldn't be bothered to read someone else's homework too closely. :o)

Comment: +1 for demonstration of `Composition` usage.

Comment: @Chris Thank you.  I tried to show several different styles in this short bit of code hoping it would be instructive to work through.

Comment: @belisarius and Anon; I thought about including additional optimizations but I decided to leave room for improvement for the OP.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it never ceases to amaze me how much I learn from your code and how I over complicate measures...:)

Comment: @ubpdqn What can I say; thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
j = 1; 
While[
 Or @@ (PrimeQ@({#-3,# - 2, # - 1, #, # + 1} &@(Total@
        IntegerDigits[Prime[j]]))), j++]
Prime[j]
```

So 8999 has desired property:

```
{#-3,# - 2, # - 1, #, # + 1} &@(Total@IntegerDigits[Prime[1117]]))
```

yields:{32, 33, 34, 35, 36}

for fun:

```
query[u_] := 
 Nor @@ PrimeQ[# + {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1} &@Total[IntegerDigits@u]]
cand = Prime[#] & /@ Range[1000, 10000]; Grid[
 Partition[PadRight[Pick[cand, query /@ cand], 168, ""], 12]]
```

The first 167 stubborn primes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional approach without using loops:

```
st[p_] := PrimeQ[Total @ IntegerDigits @ p + Range[-3, 1]] ~ AllTrue ~ Not // Not
nextStubborn[p_] := NestWhile[NextPrime, NextPrime[p], st]
stubbornList[n_] := NestList[nextStubborn, 2, n] // Rest
stubbornList[100]

(*  {8999, 18899, 19889, 19979, 19997, 28979, 29789, 29879, 35999, 36899,  *)
(*  37799, 37889, 37997, 38699, 39779, 39869, 39887, 45989, 46889, 46997,  *)
(*  47699, 47969, 48779, 48869, 49499, 49697, 49787, 49877, 55799, 55889,  *)
(*  55997, 56897, 57689, 57977, 58679, 58787, 58967, 59399, 59669, 59957,  *)
(*  64997, 65699, 65789, 66797, 66959, 66977, 67499, 67589, 67679, 67967,  *)
(*  68399, 68489, 68597, 68669, 68687, 68777, 68993, 69389, 69497, 69677,  *)
(*  69767, 69857, 69929, 71999, 74699, 74897, 75689, 75797, 75869, 76679,  *)
(*  76697, 76949, 77489, 77687, 77849, 77867, 78479, 78497, 78569, 78839,  *)
(*  78857, 78893, 78929, 79379, 79397, 79559, 79757, 79829, 79847, 79973}  *)
```

To just get the smallest:

```
nextStubborn[1]

(* 8999 *)
```

Comment: your code does not produce only primes: note-19980,28980,29790,29880, etc

Comment: Oops, it's fixed now. I often forget that Nest-related functions always return the first element.

Comment: The problem lies in `p+1`, the necessarily composite p+1 can comply with condition for exiting while

Comment: Right, that is what I meant. I should say that "I forget that the function applied zero times is included". My intuition for these things is that the first element to check a condition for in `NestWhile[f, x, g]` would be `g[f[x]]`, so my intuition often misleads me here since `g[x]` can also satisfy the break condition.