# Writing this loop in Mathematica

Tags: programming

OK, so I've never had to write a line of Mathematica code (except for using it interactively as a calculator), but for this it looks like I have to. If someone could provide me with the code for the following, then I can edit it to do what I'm actually trying to accomplish. I need to do the following:

1. Input is a set $S$ of integers and some positive integers $n,m$
2. I want to generate all the possible vectors $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ has length $n$ and $Y$ has length $m$ and the elements of each vector belong to the set $S$.
3. I need to loop over all the possible values of $X$ and $Y$.

Something like this would be trivial to write down in, say, Haskell using list comprehensions, but having flipped through the Mathematica language reference for an hour, I couldn't figure out an easy way to do this.

The values of $n$ and $m$ are such that there are about 300 million possible combinations. Therefore, it's not possible to just take Cartesian products of $S$ and then iterate over the set, unless there's a way of generating the elements in a lazy way. Otherwise the machine would run out of memory.

Comment: Welcome to the world of *Mathematica* programming!  Unfortunately I don't have the time this morning to address this question in full.  You are correct that *Mathematica* doesn't have Haskell's list comprehensions.  Usually the fastest non-compiled approach is to process in chunks.  See [(21584)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584) for a few ideas there.  It may help if you explain what you are doing with each *X* and *Y* pair.

Comment: There ARE `For` loops. Which are slow, but if you generate partial cartesian product (with `Outer`) and finish with a single `For` loop (if your set has cardinality, say, 10) that should address both the memory and the speed problems.

Comment: In the actual problem I have four of these vectors that I need to independently generate, but I only need two as an example to extrapolate from the code. I compute $X^tY$ for a bunch of these vectors to form a matrix, compute left and right kernels, check whether they intersect certain subspaces. What I need to find is values for these vectors, where the matrix and its kernel satisfies a bunch of constraints... and I hope it exists and I don't need to search the whole space.

Comment: I'm also expecting that an exhaustive search can take a week or so, but it's OK, since what I'm doing is searching for a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mathematica* has no built-in notion of Haskell-like lazy computation.  Although there have been [attempts to simulate it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/838/142), I would probably tackle this problem with a simple imperative loop.

Let's start with an example generator set, which we will call `$s`:

```
$s = Array[Prime, 20]
(* {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71} *)
```

We will now define a helper function `s` that can return a vector of any rank using elements from that set:

```
s[i__] := $s[[{i}]]
```

So now:

```
s[3, 7]
(* {5, 17} *)

s[12, 9, 15]
(* {37, 23, 47} *)
```

This enables us to write a simple `Do` loop to scan over pairs of vectors of any size.  Here is an example that scans pairs of 2-vectors and 3-vectors to find the first such pair with a nonsense property:

```
Module[{c = Length @ $s, x, y}
, Do[
    x = s[x0, x1]
  ; y = s[y0, y1, y2]
  ; If[Total[x] - Total[y] == 39, Return[{x, y}]]
  , {x0, c}, {x1, c}
  , {y0, c}, {y1, c}, {y2, c}
  ]
]

(* {{2, 43}, {2, 2, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Yes, just having the lambda operator in the language makes it possible to simulate lazynes, but doing so would be a pain. Your method is to be able to do this without that much boilerplate code. Thanks.